# How to solve in terms of one variable with an equation involving two variables?

Tags: random-variables

So I have been dealing with an extremely difficult equation: $x^{2a} = \frac{x}{a}$ and am confused on how to solve it. I am wondering how to solve for $x $ in terms of $ a$ in the case of this question. If possible, give an explanation of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to solve:
$$x^{2a} = \frac{x}{a}\implies 2a\ln(x)=\ln(x)-\ln(a)\implies \ln(x)=\frac{\ln(a)}{1-2a}$$
$$\implies x=e^{\frac{\ln(a)}{1-2a}} = \left(e^{\ln a}\right)^{{1/(1-2a)}}=a^{\frac{1}{1-2a}}.$$

Another way would be to do:

$$x^{2a} = \frac{x}{a}\implies x^{2a-1}=a^{-1}\implies x=a^{\frac{1}{1-2a}}.$$

Comment: Which can be simplified to $a^{\frac1{1-2a}}$. :)

Comment: How can this be simplified to your answer John Doe?

Comment: My guess is:

$$e^{ab} = (e^a)^b$$

Take $a$ to be the expression with the natural log here

Comment: Hello World, is there not a difference between a and e though?

Comment: Also, in the last step of the second way to complete the equation, how can x^(2a-1)=a^-1 become x=a^(1/(1-2a))?

Comment: you can take $1/(2a-1)$ power on both sides. Like if you have $x^3=y^3$ then $x=y.$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{2a}=x/a$$You can divide both sides by $x$ to get $$\frac{x^{2a}}{x}=\frac1a$$Use index rules to get $$x^{2a-1}=\frac1a$$Then raise both sides to the power $\frac1{2a-1}$ to get $$x=\left(\frac{1}a\right)^{\frac1{2a-1}}=a^{\frac1{1-2a}}$$

Comment: How can Hello World's answer be simplified to your answer?

Comment: $$e^{\frac{\ln a}{1-2a}}=(e^{\ln a})^{\frac1{1-2a}}=a^{\frac1{1-2a}}$$Since $e^{\ln a}=a$ by the fact that these are inverse functions of each other.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the way to proceed:
Hope this helps.
[image: .]